# Blender Metadata and TIFF files

Tags: rendering, output

I've had a search but can't find an answer to this.
Blender has the functionality to write various items of metadata to rendered output files (the name of the .blend file, the scene, the camera and so on). I don't mean burning in, I mean metadata in the output file. This is great for me.

However, the annoying thing is it doesn't seem to do it for TIFF files. It works for JPGs ok but, as per the documentation, TIFFs are not supported. Does anyone know why that would be? TIFF files can definitely store it, so it seems strange that this is not implemented.

The reason I ask is, I've just written a Windows Explorer shell extension that adds a tab to the file properties dialog. It shows any Blender-related metadata if there is any. This is useful to me so that I can track back to the blend file and scene of the source of the image (whenever I need to go back and re-render it). However, (of course), I usually render in TIFF format and hence... no data.

[image: File Properties Dialog]

Thanks
Steve

Comment: There are no Blender developers here nor is anyone here associated with the Blender Foundation so you'll have to ask the developers directly or suggest it at https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @johneaston. Yeah, I previously tried getting a login to RCS but it said its closed to new registrations so I thought I'd chance my arm here (just in case anyone might know the answer).